# Does interaction mean covariance, not correlation?

Tags: regression, covariance

For example
let's say that we want to predict math scores by income and history score (non standardized, raw score), and their interaction

y = b1(history) + b2(income) + b3(history*income)

the meaning of b3 is significant: income and history scores moderate each other on math score

In that case, does that mean that history and income covary?

(not correlate. history and income can have no -correlation and simultaneously have high covariance.
income and history are IV, and let's assume that history and income show no correlation here. )

Comment: "history and income can have no correlation and simultaneously have high covariance" seems an unlikely statement if they have finite variances

Comment: @Henry you can see it by basic example. ```r   income<-rnorm(100,0,1)    history <- rnorm(100,0,1)``` This has low cov and low cor. However, if you do ```income2<-9999*income, and history2 <- 9999*history ``` you will see high cov between income2 and history2

Comment: That is just scaling: your first pair of variables each have variances near $1$ so the  covariance and correlation are close; your second pair of variables each have variances near $100000000$ so the  covariance is about that number times the correlation - it might look big, but in the context it is not.  Since you took independent (pseudo-)random samples, you can say that all those correlations and covariances will be relatively small (most of the time).  Increase the sample sizes and they will usually be even smaller

Comment: @Henry Yes, but due to scaling, the cov between two variable becomes really high (not correlation, which means standardized cov) does this scaling can be mistakenly captured as interaction?